# GWT + Lucene-spatial (via Hibernate Search)

Tags: java, lucene, spatial, hibernate-search

Ok I have re-phrased the question a bit as I have made some progress...

Hi,

I have been searching around for the last day (badly) to try to find some help on how to use Lucene-Spatial within my application.

I am using GWT so I would like to keep the client side clear of org.apache.* packages as GWT tries to serialise everything on the client side. (made this tutorial less useful : [url]http://java.dzone.com/articles/spatial-search-hibernate?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+javalobby/frontpage+(Javalobby+/+Java+Zone)[/url])

Basically I have an address object with a field "latitude" and a field "longitude" and I would like to do distance searches against this, is lucene-spatial the right way to go or should I look more into doing it in another way?

So far I have got to :-

[code]DistanceQueryBuilder dq = new DistanceQueryBuilder(new Double(point[1]), new Double(point[0]), 10d,
                        "activity_locationName_latitude", "activity_locationName_longitude",CartesianTierPlotter.DEFALT_FIELD_PREFIX, true);

```
            FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);


            org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( new ConstantScoreQuery(dq.getFilter()) );[/code]
```

But I dont understand what "CartesianTierPlotter.DEFALT_FIELD_PREFIX" is meant to actually be, and as such my result set comes back empty.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a GWT app that uses Lucene / Hibernate Search but not Lucene spatial.

Is the issue you having very specific to the use of Lucene spatial? If not, then I could assist since I set all the Lucene / Hibernate Search stuff in our GWT app and it works like a charm (in other words I am using classes from org.apache.lucene with in a GWT-based app).

Comment: I have integrated some simple search mechanics and they are great, it is a distance search that I am currently working on (hence I have turned to spatial) But I dont really understand it and have struggled to find tutorials.  I have however found this guide [link]http://java.dzone.com/articles/spatial-search-hibernate?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+javalobby/frontpage+(Javalobby+/+Java+Zone)[/link] But the second block of code requires a module from org.apache.spatial to be client side which means GWT wants to serialise it.  Unless I am just being a fool..? :)

Comment: Seems very strange to me that you would need any lucene stuff client-side. I highly doubt this. When you refer to the "second block of code" do you mean the one containing @FieldBridge(impl=CartesianTierFieldBridgeImpl.class)? This is definitely server-side. In fact, unless I'm being stupid, all of the code in this tutorial seems to be server-side.

Comment: The way this should work is you update your model and create the field bridge (all server side) then your client should just be sending query terms (just as a String probably) to the server which then runs the distance search and sends the results to the client. The client should not know about how the query is being run at all, i.e. it has no idea that Lucene / Hibernate Search exists at all.

Comment: I think maybe I am getting confused as the annotations are on the client.domain.address object which is where I thought that you had to add the @FieldBridge(impl=CartesianTierFieldBridgeImpl.class) .  Will have a play around in a bit and try again and let you know if I have any joy.  Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Could you give me some pointers on how to integrate GWT with lucene and a db? i am not sure whether i should put the index in db or file system? i am not using hibernate, but am open to using it.